# Creating a dinamic table from a DataFrame values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
` Do you smoke? Do you exercise? Do you sleep less than 8 hours?
0           yes               no                       sometimes
1            no              yes                              no
2     sometimes              yes                             yes
3            no              yes                       sometimes
4            no               no                              no
5           yes               no                             yes`
```

and I would like to group the "yes , no , sometimes" answers such that I can get the percentage of people who said yes, no and sometimes in each question!.

How should I proceed?

Comment: What is your expected result? What have you tried? Please [edit] your post to show your [honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a *specific* question about your technique and/or result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value_counts()` for the occurrences and `count()` for the length of the columns:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
"Do you smoke?": ['yes', 'no', 'sometimes', 'no', 'no', 'yes'], 
"Do you exercise?": ['no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no'], 
"Do you sleep less than 8 hours?": ['sometimes', 'no', 'yes', 'sometimes', 'no', 'yes']
})

results = [df[col].value_counts() / df[col].count() for col in df]

print(results)
```

Output:

```py
[
no           0.500000
yes          0.333333
sometimes    0.166667
Name: Do you smoke?, dtype: float64, 
no     0.5
yes    0.5
Name: Do you exercise?, dtype: float64, 
sometimes    0.333333
no           0.333333
yes          0.333333
Name: Do you sleep less than 8 hours?, dtype: float64
]
```